# AWS Cloudformation - How to manually add/delete an export?

Tags: amazon-web-services, export, aws-cloudformation

Is there a way to add/delete an export manually, say via the console? I could not find any info regarding this?

Answer (score 2):

No. Everything in CloudFormation is controlled via the **template** file.

You would need to edit the template to add/remove the export, then **update the stack** to invoke the change.